# Encoding issue with accented letter passenger RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, rbenv

I have a bug when I run a RoR application on an Ubuntu server, my config is : ubuntu 14.04 - nginx - passenger 5.0.9 - rbenv - ruby 2.2.2 - rails 4.2.1. Everything works fine with a default config but when I try to change an environment variable and put an accented letter in it, I get an error when I read it from Ruby. My locales are correctly set to en_US.UTF-8. The error occurs in an HAML file. The backtrace is https://gist.github.com/Uelb/207cd29ffd91185529b6 . When I get the env variable from my console and send a `to_json`, I have no error and I see the accented letter correctly.

Comment: Is your database set up to be utf8 as well?

Comment: Yes, but I do not use the database in this operation. Also, the database contains a lot of special characters, and none of them is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by explicitly setting the env variable LC_ALL to LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 in the rbenv-vars plugin file.